# Can the Aragon SDK pass any encoded action abitrarily?

Tags: solidity, dao, abiencoderv2, encodefunctioncall

In the examples section of the [SDK documentation](https://devs.aragon.org/docs/sdk), there are encoders for a bunch of common DAO operations.

However I can't see an encoding for an arbitrary contract call in the examples.

Does the SDK support arbitrary calls yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any arbitrary action that you can encode using an existing library.

So, if you know the function signature, you can use `ethers.js` to initialize its interface and then pass the `calldata` bytes to the proposal’s action array. You can find documentation on how to pass actions to proposals here: https://devs.aragon.org/docs/sdk/examples/tokenVoting-client/create-proposal-with-actions
These actions get executed when a proposal passes.

What the SDK can’t possibly do is detecting/decoding `calldata` for functions it knows nothing about. In such case, you would need to have your function signatures ready to match all incoming actions that you create.